# g++ not destructing thread locals

Tags: c++, g++, thread-local

On my machine, GCC is not calling the destructors of `thread_local`s.
The code runs fine on clang 7 and Visual Studio.

Is this a bug?
I'm using MinGW GCC 8.1 on Windows.

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "A()\n";
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "~A()\n";
    }

    void
    print() {
        std::cout << "A\n";
    }
};

thread_local A a;

int
main() {
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, works on Coliru (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6221152ec61be165)

Comment: Seeing loads of bugs listed in a Google search for "mingw thread_local" - is this one of them?

Comment: Does it happen when you create a thread, use the thread local in the thread, then clean the tthread up before main ends?